# App to Change Ldap Password for a JIRA/SVN server

Tags: svn, ldap, passwords, web-applications

I'm setting up a server to offer JIRA and SVN.  I figure, I'll use LDAP to keep the identity management simple.

So, before I write one....  is there a good app out there to let users change their ldap password?  I want something that lets a user authenticate with ldap and update their password.  A form with username, old password, new password and verification would be enough.

I can write my own, but it seems silly to do so if there's already a good app out there that handles this....

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks.  I broke down and wrote my own.  I used the google web toolkit.  It was pretty trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try [LDAP Self Service Portal](http://rubyforge.org/projects/ossp/).

We had the same need, but finally used the [Account Manager plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin) for [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), the collaborative environment we are using.